# Opencart - remove shipping from invoice only

Tags: opencart2.x

Im trying to remove shipping line from opencart 2.0.1.1 invoice (remove shipping only on invoice page) and realize that it is not posible on template view becuase 
$total['text'];   hold subtotal , shipping and Total. Where in controller or model I can remove only shipping, please look image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p06Mm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to remove shipping only in Invoice page. After removing shipping price total will be a mismatch. If you really want to remove shipping in the invoice then make following condition in your invoice template file.

```
<?php if($total['title'] == 'Flat Shipping Rate'){?>
       //Black
<?php }else{?>
      // Code here
<?php }?>
```